# I need to extend to fragment but also listactivity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Android studio. So basically I MainActivity I have NavigationDrawer that I use to go to fragments. When I open this fragment I need it to display a Listview. The problem is in order for listview to work I need to extend to listactivity, but in order to open fragment from menu I need to extend to Fragment. What to do?

Heres my MainActivity navigation drawer

```
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (id == R.id.nav_main) {
        // Handle the camera action
        fragment = new WebListFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_add) {

        // Handle the camera action
        fragment = new AddFragment();

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_tut) {

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

Here's my fragment

public class WebListFragment extends Fragment{

```
public WebListFragment() {}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    String[] links = {"Facebook", "Twitter", "StackOverflow"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(getListView().getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, links);
    getListView().setAdapter(adapter);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_web_list, container, false);
}
```

Comment: `for listview to work I need to extend to listactivity` why? You don't have to

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You totally don't have to use `ListActivity` just create `ListView` as you would normally do and then set the adapter. Then you can extend Fragment without a problem

```
ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvMain);
lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is in order for listview to work I need to extend to listactivity

`ListActivity` is a convenience class. You can use a `ListView` without a `ListActivity`.

> in order to open fragment from menu I need to extend to Fragment

Or, you can extend from a class that itself inherits from `Fragment`.

> What to do?

You could [use `ListFragment`](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ListFragment.html). Or, you could use `Fragment`, and just manage the `ListView` the same as you would any other widget.